# Completing elements in columns in R using elements from other 2 columns

Tags: r, date

I have a `.csv` file with the following data:

```
duration time | starting time | finish time 
1,#1996-06-18 23:25:00#,#1996-06-18 23:26:00#

23,#1996-06-18 23:28:00#,#1996-06-18 23:51:00#
```

**1,#1996-06-18 23:59:00#,#1996-06-19#**

```
1,#1996-06-18 23:24:00#,#1996-06-18 23:25:00#

8,#1996-06-18 23:51:00#,#1996-06-18 23:59:00#
```

**3,#1996-06-19#,#1996-06-19 00:03:00#**

```
12,#1996-06-19 00:12:00#,#1996-06-19 00:24:00#

3,#1996-06-18 23:03:00#,#1996-06-18 23:06:00#
```

The bold lines have incomplete elements. My question is how can i **complete the those elements**(start time and finish time) using the duration and the other element, i.e sum the duration and the start time to obtain the finish time, **in R (assuming that this data is in a data frame).**

Basically, how do i add 00:00:00 to these rows (in a R data frame)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lubridate` package to convert the duration column to time objects. Using the `dplyr` package you can manipulate your data.frame as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(duration = c(1, 23, 1, 1, 8, 3),
             start_time = c("1996-06-18 23:25:00",
                            "1996-06-18 23:28:00",
                            "1996-06-18 23:59:00",
                            "1996-06-18 23:24:00",
                            "1996-06-18 23:51:00",
                            "1996-06-19"),
             end_time = c("1996-06-18 23:26:00", 
                          "1996-06-18 23:51:00", 
                          "1996-06-19",
                          "1996-06-18 23:25:00", 
                          "1996-06-18 23:59:00",
                          "1996-06-19 00:03:00"))

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(start_time = as.POSIXct(start_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), duration = minutes(duration),
         end_time = as.POSIXct(end_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  mutate(start_time = ifelse(is.na(start_time),
                             (end_time - duration),
                             start_time),
         end_time = ifelse(is.na(end_time), 
                          (start_time + duration),
                          end_time))

df1 %<>%
  mutate(start_time = as.POSIXct(start_time, origin = "1970-01-01"),
         end_time = as.POSIXct(end_time, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

and then your output would look like this:

```
> df1
  duration          start_time            end_time
1    1M 0S 1996-06-18 23:25:00 1996-06-18 23:26:00
2   23M 0S 1996-06-18 23:28:00 1996-06-18 23:51:00
3    1M 0S 1996-06-18 23:59:00 1996-06-19 00:00:00
4    1M 0S 1996-06-18 23:24:00 1996-06-18 23:25:00
5    8M 0S 1996-06-18 23:51:00 1996-06-18 23:59:00
6    3M 0S 1996-06-19 00:00:00 1996-06-19 00:03:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!